# How to catch error from invoked function?

Tags: php, try-catch, invoke

Alright, i have a problem to `catch` an `error` or `exception` when i call an `undefined` `function`

I have a methode to invoke a function, with two parameter `(bool, function)`

```
private function invoking($hdr = true, $fnc) {
   if(is_callable($fnc)) {
      if($hdr) {
         $this->load_header();
      }

      try {
        $fnc->__invoke();
      } catch(Exception $er) {
        echo "Something went wrong. ".$er;
      }
   } else {
       echo "function not callable";
   }
}
```

But, i have a problem to catch the error inside `$fnc`.

```
$this->invoking(true, function() {
   undefinedfunction();
   // for example i called this, which the function doesnt exist
});
```

But seems like the catch doesnt not work to what inside i `__invoke()`, what should i do to catch the error inside `invoked` function?

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But seems like the catch doesnt not work to what inside i __invoke()

It doesn't work because it throws a `Fatal error` which can't be handled using `Exception` class. And prior to PHP 7 it was almost impossible to catch those kind of errors.

In PHP 7 :

> Most errors are now reported by throwing Error exceptions

Read more on [Errors in PHP 7](http://php.net/manual/en/language.errors.php7.php)

So if your php version is >= PHP 7 you can simply do it like this

```
  try {
    $fnc->__invoke();
  } catch(Error $er) { // Error is the base class for all internal PHP errors
    echo $er->getMessage();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are executing the undefinedfunction before passing it
you need to be doing :

```
$this->invoking(true,'undefinedfunction');
```

Then __invoke won't work on a string so you need to use

```
call_user_func($fnc);
```

instead.

To invoke functions that has arguments pass the arguments as array to your function then to 
call_user_func_array

```
private function invoking($hdr = true, $fnc, $args=Array())
...
call_user_func_array($fnc, $args);
...
$this->invoking(true,'print_r', Array("Hi there It Works"));
```

So your final code would be :

```
private function invoking($hdr = true, $fnc, $args=Array()) {
   if(is_callable($fnc)) {
      if($hdr) {
         $this->load_header();
      }

      try {
        call_user_func_array($fnc, $args);
      } catch(Exception $er) {
        echo "Something went wrong. ".$er;
      }
   } else {
       echo "function not callable";
   }
}
```

Tests :

```
$this->invoking(true,'undefinedfunction');
$this->invoking(true,'print_r', Array("Hi there It Works"));
```